# Loop list in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a list :

```
public List<Sale> AllSales { get; set; }
```

And i would like to loop it in jquery :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

            for (var i = 0; i < <%= AllSales %>; i++) {
                 alert("test");
            }

         });
```

But i am not getting any alerts or anything, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Count` property, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        for (var i = 0; i < <%= AllSales.Count %>; i++) {
             alert("test");
        }

});
```

Comment: @syncis Upvoted you, it really seems a legitimate question, don't know why you were downvoted with no comment...

Comment: @Blanchshma I thought it was you that was downvoting me, just didnt understand whats was wrong with the question but i got a perfect answer at least.

Comment: @syncis I just retagged the question as asp.net and jquery instead of c# and .net becuase this is a jQuery question...

Comment: @Blanchshma ok totally understand, still dont think the downvote was necessary, you could just have helped me with tags :))

Comment: @syncis I repeat, it wasn't me who downvote you - I just edited the quesiton to change the tags...  It's not the same thing :) Unless the downvoter writes a comment, you have no way of knowing who he was... But atleast you got my upvote :)

Comment: Thank you for your help friend ! 3 mins left before i can accept answer :P

Answer (score 2):

Use `AllSales.Count` instead of `AllSales` to limit the loop. If you want to access values of the list then you may need to use `ajax` to bring the values to javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     for (var i = 0; i < <%= AllSales.Count %>; i++) {
             alert("test");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get the count of dropdown objects:

```
var myCount = $('#myDropDown > option');
```

... and then use this new variable in your loop definition.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your type View

```
@model List<Sale>
```

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < <%= Model.Count %>; i++) {
    // operations...
}
```

If it is a property of your model, so, try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < <%= Model.AllSales.Count %>; i++) {
   // operations...
}
```

I also recoment you change from `List<Sale>` to `IEnumerable<Sale>` and use `Count()` from method to get the lenght of the list from `System.Linq` . `IEnumerable` is more abstract than `List` and you will be protected to add items on the List on View scope.